# Master pages on website but there are no master pages in source code in asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, master-pages

I got source code of website which have included master pages but master pages are not included in source code. I have tried to put the same master page which i made myself and try to execute on it but it doesn't work. It seems there is already some master pages which i can see in published files but i cannot find in source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didnt select `Allow this precompiled site to be updatable` then Master Pages won't appear in your source code as they are compiled into the `bin` folder as `.dll` files.

If you open up any .aspx file you will see that the content is just:

```
This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!
```

If you need to be able to edit the markup code in the published version of the site, ensure that `Allow this precompiled site to be updatable` is selected when publishing.

Comment: Do you need to be able to edit the Master Pages once the site has been published? If so, publish the site again, but this time make sure you select `Allow this precompiled site to be updatable`

Comment: I have got the published source code from client. I want to extract the master pages from this published source code.

Comment: Sounds like you don't really have the source code, only the published (compiled) version.

Comment: Yes but i just need for master pages only.

Comment: In this case, you will need to get hold of the original source files, or decompile the site. This article may be helpful: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/080404-1.aspx